# Strange UI issue for different sdk's

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios6

I have two machines running xcode 4.3.1 and xcode 4.6 respectively.
 Here is sdk's for above Xcode's----

```
 xcode 4.3.1  --> iOS sdk 5.1
 xcode 4.6    --> iOS sdk 6.1
```

So when i build my source code against iOS sdk 5.1 
   Every thing is fine no issues but when i build the same code with iOS sdk 6.1
   There are UI distortion issues .
So my question is ....
Is it a iOS sdk issue or xcode or iOS issue.

**EDIT**
@shivan Here is screen shot of our distorted UI

Thnx Ilya Ilin , But if UI is designed with Interface builder 3.2 and now we are in process to upgrade the app with Xcode 4.6 for iOS 6.x

[image]

Regards,
Paggyyyy

Comment: UI Distortion... Can you give us screenshots?

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off autolayout
[image]

...or give the issues message.